# How to properly create a class to hold data from JSON with Alamofire and SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm trying to create a class to hold data from webservice sent as JSON. Here is the JSON I'm getting back from the server:

```
[  
  {  
    "weekSchedule":[  
      {  
        "weekDay":"sunday",
        "listening":[  
          {  
            "textName":"Programa de teste 1",
            "textPresenter":"Apresentador",
            "timeStartHour":"08:00:00",
            "timeEndHour":"23:59:00",
            "textDescription":"Descri\u00e7\u00e3o do programa ",
            "textGuest":"Dr. Lair Ribeiro",
            "urlImage":"file:\/\/servidor\/lampp\/webservice\/img\/happy.png"
          },
          {  
            "textName":"Teste 2",
            "textPresenter":"Teste",
            "timeStartHour":"00:00:00",
            "timeEndHour":"00:00:00",
            "textDescription":"",
            "textGuest":"",
            "urlImage":"file:\/\/servidor\/lampp\/webservice\/img\/happy.png"
          }
        ]
      },
      {  
        "weekDay":"monday",
        "listening":[  
          {  
            "textName":"Programa de teste 1",
            "textPresenter":"Apresentador",
            "timeStartHour":"08:00:00",
            "timeEndHour":"23:59:00",
            "textDescription":"Descri\u00e7\u00e3o do programa ",
            "textGuest":"Dr. Lair Ribeiro",
            "urlImage":"file:\/\/servidor\/lampp\/webservice\/img\/happy.png"
          },
          {  
            "textName":"Programa teste marco",
            "textPresenter":"Marco",
            "timeStartHour":"08:30:00",
            "timeEndHour":"09:30:00",
            "textDescription":"Apenas um programa para testar o json",
            "textGuest":"Jason",
            "urlImage":"file:\/\/servidor-ubuntu\/lampp\/webservice\/img\/happy.png"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here are the model classes I'm creating (Need help here!)

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON

class Show: ResponseJSONObjectSerializable {

  var name: String?
  var description: String?
  var host: String?
  var guest: String?
  var startTime: String?
  var endTime: String?
  var urlImage: String?

  required init(json: JSON) {
    self.name = json["textName"].string
    self.description = json["textDescription"].string
    self.host = json["textPresenter"].string
    self.guest = json["textGuest"].string
    self.startTime = json["timeStartHour"].string
    self.endTime = json["timeEndHour"].string
    self.urlImage = json["urlImage"].string
  }

  required init() {}
}

class ShowArray: ResponseJSONObjectSerializable {

  var weekday: String?
  var showArray: [Show]?

  required init?(json: JSON) {

    self.weekday = json["weekDay"].string

    if let jsonArray = json["listening"].array {
      self.showArray = []

      for json in jsonArray {
        let instance = Show(json: json)
        self.showArray?.append(instance)
      }
    }
  }

}

class ScheduleArray: ResponseJSONObjectSerializable {

  var scheduleArray: [ShowArray]?

  required init?(json: JSON) {

    if let weekArray = json["weekSchedule"].array {
      self.scheduleArray = []

      for weekDay in weekArray {
        let instance = ShowArray(json: weekDay)
        self.scheduleArray?.append(instance!)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The Alamofire function to make the http request:

```
func getWeeklyShedule(completionHandler: (Result<ScheduleArray, NSError>) -> Void) {

    alamofireManager.request(RCAppRouter.GetSchedule()).responseObject {
      (response: Response<ScheduleArray, NSError>) in

      guard response.result.isSuccess else {
        print("Error fetching schedule: \(response.result.error!)")
        return
      }

      completionHandler(response.result)
    }
  }
```

Then in my view controller I need to hold the listings on an array of Show

```
var listings = [Show]()
RCAPIManager.sharedInstance.getWeeklyShedule {
      (result) in

      guard result.error == nil else {
        print("Error")
        return
      }

      guard let fetchedSchedule = result.value else {
        print("No schedule fetched")
        return
      }

      self.listings = fetchedSchedule.scheduleArray ???

    }
```

This is where I got stuck, how can I loop through the object to store the data from listings to my array of Show?

Any tips on how to refactor my code to achieve, The expected result is a segmented control for each day o the week, when pressed I'll use it as a filter to display the appropriated information.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Just an FYI for your note. Write the networking code using NSURLSession and parse the data yourself into a proper model. You should not rely on inspection and reflection on models to assign them variables. Remove the necessary dependency for Alamofire altogether.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @TheCodingArt, I'll try that! But could you tell me why I should not rely on Alamofire for my aproach?

Comment: You're adding a dependency as a light wrapper for no real benefit/gain/reason. It's really an anti pattern and leads to headaches down the road.

Comment: Thanks again @TheCodingArt I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the prettiest way but it'll work.

```
if let responseArray = response as? NSArray {
    for i in 0..<responseArray.count {
    let showDic = responseArray[i] as! NSDictionary
    let dayOfWeek = showDic["weekday"] as! String
    let showArray = showDic["listening"] as! NSArray
        switch dayOfWeek {
        case "sunday":
           addShowObjectsToArray(showArray, dailyShows: sundayArray)
        case "monday":
           addShowObjectsToArray(showArray, dailyShows: mondayArray)
        case "tuesday":
           addShowObjectsToArray(showArray, dailyShows: tuesdayArray)
        case "wednseday":
           addShowObjectsToArray(showArray, dailyShows: wednsedayArray)
        case "thursday":
           addShowObjectsToArray(showArray, dailyShows: thursdayArray)
        case "friday":
           addShowObjectsToArray(showArray, dailyShows: fridayArray)
        case "saturday":
           addShowObjectsToArray(showArray, dailyShows: saturdayArray)
        default:
        }
    }

func addShowObjectsToArray(shows: NSArray, dailyShows: NSArray) {
    for show in shows {
        let showObject = Show(show)
        dailyShows.append(showObject)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @brl214 after fiddling around with your answer I did figure out my own question. I like the ideia of the switch though I'll definitely use it for the segcontrol!

Comment: @acmobile No problem! Happy you figured it out!!

Answer (score 0):

I got what I wanted by changing three things:

```
func getWeeklyShedule(completionHandler: (Result<[ScheduleArray], NSError>) -> Void) {

    alamofireManager.request(RCAppRouter.GetSchedule()).responseArray {
      (response: Response<[ScheduleArray], NSError>) in

      guard response.result.isSuccess else {
        print("Error fetching schedule: \(response.result.error!)")
        return
      }

      completionHandler(response.result)
    }
  }
```

(Result) <==> (Result<[ScheduleArray], NSError>)

.responseObject <==> .responseArray

(response: Response) <==> (response: Response<[ScheduleArray], NSError>)